# Is there a way to get a spearmans correlation matrix for more than two arrays?

Tags: math.net

I have code that produces N arrays of doubles and I'd like to create a spearmans correlation matrix. Is there a function to do it for me or do I have to iterate through all the combinations and build my own correlation matrix with [Correlation.Spearman()](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/Correlation.htm#Spearman)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no routine to compute a correlation matrix yet, but I've opened ticket [#161](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/161) to track it at GitHub.

In the meantime, you could use the following routine (I'm using [v3.0.0-alpha5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/3.0.0-alpha5) here):

```
Matrix<double> Spearman(double[][] data)
{
    var m = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseIdentity(data.Length);
    for(int i=0; i<data.Length; i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<data.Length; j++)
    {
        var c = Correlation.Spearman(data[i], data[j]);
        m.At(i,j,c);
        m.At(j,i,c);
    }
    return m;
}

var vectors = new[] {
    new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
    new[] { 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0 },
    new[] { 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 },
    new[] { 0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0 },
    new[] { 2.0, 4.0, -4.0, 2.0 }
};

Spearman(vectors);
```

Which will return:

```
DenseMatrix 5x5-Double
           1            1           -1     0.948683    -0.316228
           1            1           -1     0.948683    -0.316228
          -1           -1            1    -0.948683     0.316228
    0.948683     0.948683    -0.948683            1            0
   -0.316228    -0.316228     0.316228            0            1
```

**Update 2013-10-20:**

Added to master, available in V3.0.0-alpha6 and newer:

- `Correlation.PearsonMatrix(params double[][] vectors)`
- `Correlation.PearsonMatrix(IEnumerable<double[]> vectors)`
- `Correlation.SpearmanMatrix(params double[][] vectors)`
- `Correlation.SpearmanMatrix(IEnumerable<double[]> vectors)`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with a case specific solution since I don't need the whole matrix. Watching the github issue thread though, because this will be useful in the future.